# lodash filter array of objects by array Angular 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, lodash

Say I have an object like so...

[image]

and I have an array with ids like this..

```
array = ['21d32fwef23fw32f3', '21we3weasdf23rfwfwf3']
```

how can I return only the objects that have `sys.ids` that match the `ids` in the `array`

Ive tried using lodash like so..

```
getWeekItems(weekNumber) {
  this.contenfulService.getWeekItems(weekNumber)
    .then((weekOverview) => {
       this.weekOverviewCompleted = _.filter(weekOverview, this.completedIds);
       console.log(this.weekOverviewCompleted);
      }).then(() => console.log(this.weekOverview));
  }
```

but Im getting an empty array back??

is there a better way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can get the filtered result :

```
_.filter(weekOverview, (item) => {
  return this.completedIds.indexOf(item.sys.id) > -1 ;
});

// OR Simple javascript filter function

weekOverview.filter(item => {
  return this.completedIds.indexOf(item.sys.id) > -1 ;    
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks! Do you know how I could do the opposite? so only return the items that don't match those ids??

Answer (score 0):

JS function 'filter' does not work on mobile devices. Use the same function defined in Lodash library.